# Cual es la solucion? ,no arranca el servidor con NPM START, Node JS

Tags: nodejs, npm

problemas al arrancar servidor a través del script NPM "START" = "node index.js[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]"

Comment: no tienes permisos en la carpera que quieres ejecutar el script, verifica que permisos tiene y en que grupo esta el archivo que quieres ejecutar y los cambias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles, además es preferible el código y el mensaje de error en formato texto y no en una imagen. Al parecer tienes problemas con los permisos de usuario. Ocurre al instalar `node` usando `sudo`. Saludos